# How to remove features from built in components in Angular4

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a beginner in the front-end technologies. I am using angular 4 and want to reuse the data-table here :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-4-data-table-bootstrap-4

I want to remove the menu and refresh button on the top as shown here:
https://github.com/afermon/angular-4-data-table-bootstrap-4-demo

Please, can someone guide me how to do that. If I make changes in my local node_modules, I believe it won't reflect when the application is deployed on a server.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the source code for `angular-4-data-table-bootstrap-4`.

I just had a look, and unfortunately there is no boolean flag to toggle the visibility.

But you can hide the buttons by applying the following styles in the global `styles.css` file.

```
.refresh-button {
    display: none;
}

.column-selector-button {
    display: none;  
}
```